# Как в twig-шаблоне использовать константу класса сущности?

Tags: symfony, twig

Пока приходится писать

```
{% if order.status == 1 %}
```

А хочется написать корректно:

```
{% if order.status == Order::NEW %}
```

Подскажите хотя бы ссылку на документацию.

Comment: [Вот так](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/constant.html). [Ну и для 3 версии вроде тоже самое](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tests/constant.html)

Comment: @Simon Спасибо, помогло